# Проблема с выбором подгружаемой страницы.

Tags: php

Всем привет! Хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение.

Есть реализация загрузки необходимой страницы, предположим что этот код находится по ссылке http://test.ru/city.php:

```
<?php 
    switch ($_REQUEST['CITY']) {
case moscow: // Если город Москва, то подключаем страницу moscow.php
    $url = "http://test.ru/moscow.php";
    break;
default: // Если все остальные города, то подключаем страницу anyone.php
    $url = "http://test.ru/anyone.php";
}
header('Location: ' . $url);
exit;
?>
```

После подгруженной страницы, допустим, я хочу сменить город, у меня на странице есть специальный блок, с помощью которого я выбираю в выпадающем списке нужный мне город и жмякаю по нему. Этот блок приклеивает к **URL** страницы, на которой я нахожусь в данный момент, передаваемый параметр, допустим, **http://test.ru/city.php?CITY = moscow**. После этого мне загрузилась страница **http://test.ru/moscow.php**, поскольку  переданный параметр был **moscow**. Дальше я снова хочу сменить город, выбираю из списка другой город, **НО** я же нахожусь уже на странице **http://test.ru/moscow.php**, и получается, что *URL* уже будет выглядеть вот так **http://test.ru/moscow.php?CITY=anyone**, по сути, мне отобразится та же страница **http://test.ru/moscow.php**, а надо приклеить передаваемый параметр снова к **URL** страницы **http://test.ru/city.php**. 
Жестко привязать ссылку в блоке к странице **http://test.ru/city.php я не могу**, сами понимаете, поскольку блок смены города присоединяет передаваемый параметр к **URL** страницы на которой я нахожусь в данный момент.
Вариант прописать **switch** в каждой странице не прокатит.
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться!

Comment: Когда "Жмякаете" по нужному городу - делайте редирект через header на http://test.ru/city.php с параметром города. а он уже выполнит редирект на нужную страницу с нужным url.

Comment: @archi_sova, то есть, при выборе региона, вам надо чтоб появлялась форма, которая соответствует этому выбору? Если да, то вам не нужно переходить на какую-то другую страницу, а просто выводить ту или иную форму... толи из базы, толи из файла и т.д.
P.S. И я не могу вам дать точный ответ, т.к. не знаю как у вас работает скрипт, да и вообще, как устроена структура сайта.

Comment: А редирект не получается потому что, параметр GLOBAL_CITY летит на страницу online_form.php (если я на ней нахожусь), а обработчик находится в файле online_form_connect.php (в нем мой switch описан), т.е. получается что GLOBAL_CITY=(условно Уфа) я передаю на страницу online_form.php поскольку на ней стою то мой блок приклеивает к URL online_form.php?GLOBAL_CITY=1525, но обработчика на странице online_form.php нету и сделать я его там не могу поскольку если сделаю то меня будет постоянно зацикливать на одной и той же странице.

Comment: @Deonis, к сожалению дописать RewriteRule - тоже не могу, точнее могу но нельзя так делать. А так впринципе согласен - Да! это решение. Но нельзя :(

Comment: Мде... Как говорят в Одессе: "Вы делаете мне сердцебиение" =). То нельзя, это нельзя. Даже не знаю, что вам и сказать.

Comment: :) Блин уже и комментариев не хватает. Ладно благодраю за то что не отказались помочь!

Comment: @Deonis, буду рад еще услышать советы и комментарии на эту темы :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подключите на нужных страницах обработчик, который будет принимать GET-запрос с парметром CITY и переадресовывать на нужную страницу или же вытягивать необходимые данные из БД на страницу.

Comment: Он всегда существует, предположим что по-умолчанию я перехожу на страницу http://test.ru/city.php уже с параметром CITY = moscow, т.е. страница служит для первоначального определения региона, т.е. если в блоке ранее было выбран другой регион то уже на страницу http://test.ru/city.php я попаду с параметром anyone, соответственно если ранее был выбран moscow значит и на страницу попаду с параметром moscow, а уже страница city.php меня перенаправит на нужную страничку. Надо что со страниц moscow.php и anyone.php я мог перейти соответственно на нужную страницу при выборе в блоке нужного города

Comment: Там получается, что при переходе на страницу online_form_connect.php происходит перенаправление по выбранному региону допустим была МОСКВА, я попадаю на страницу допустим online_form.php, а потом на этой же странице online_form.php выбираю регион УФА, мне должна отобразится страница online_form_ufa.php, но я ведь передал параметр GLOBAL_CITY на страницу online_form.php а не на страницу online_form_connect.php где собственно и прописан редирект, поэтому мне снова отображается страница online_form.php.

Comment: подключить не могу т.к. все переменные GET уничтожаются где-то раньше по коду а достать GLOBAL_CITY я могу только из $_REQUEST['REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY']), или мот я чето не понимаю, мот она и не уничтожается, но просто ехом я ее точно отобразить не могу, поэтому и решил что уничтожается.

Comment: Сейчас глянул и у вас таки используется mod_rewrite. Значит надо искать или "выше по коду", или как предложил @DDD (ответ ниже) - дописать правило в .htaccess.

Comment: Ааааа все получилось :) Допер, как вы и говорили дописал просто счетчик:
<?php
 //echo "<p style='color: red;'>Загрузился файл - <strong>online_form_ufa.php</strong></p>";+
 $RSC = $_REQUEST['REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY'];
 echo "Мы пришли со страницы: <b>". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."</b><br>";
 echo "Переменная <b>REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY</b> существует и она равна: ".$RSC;
 
 if(isset($_REQUEST['REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY']) && $_REQUEST['REGIONALBANK_SM_CITY'] == 1054){
  $url = "http://alfa.rbrbank.ru/clients/private/crediting/consumer/online_form_ufa.php";
  header('Location: ' . $url);
 }
?>

Comment: Вот и ладушки ))

Answer (score 0):

В .htaccess добавить

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ city.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Все запросы будут поступать в файл city.phр и в зависимости от запроса, подгружайте нужную информацию.

Comment: не работает :(

Comment: Вот все таки интересное решение с RewriteRule, я туту погуглил на счет этого, мот я все таки не правильно строку составил, можете подсказать как будет выглядеть для это странички http://alfa.rbrbank.ru/clients/private/crediting/consumer/online_form_connect.php